# nginx error log was huge, so I deleted and created a new one, now nginx won't start

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, log-files

I deleted the **/var/log/nginx/error.log** file, and then created a new one using:

```
sudo nano error.log
```

Doing `ls -la` shows that the **error.log** and **access.log** have the same permissions.

When I try and start nginx I get the error:

> alert: could not open error log file: open()
>   "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed permission denited.

**Update**

When trying to start nginx, I am also seeing:

> emerg: /var/run/nginx.pid failed 13: permission denied.

Comment: Delete the Log and restart or reload Nginx. It will automatically create the Log.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This doesn't solve your problem, but in the future, if you do

> cat /dev/null >
>   /file/you/want/to/wipe-out

you will copy over the contents of the file with nothing, and keep all permissions in tact.

Not nginx-speicific, but Additionally, make sure you are running the application as the user it is supposed to run as.  If you ever ran it as root, all the permissions are going to be owned by root, so other users won't be able to run it.

Comment: How is it different from using `echo "" > /file/to/empty`? Are they both the same?

Comment: That should be the same.  Additionally, you can leave out all the stuff at the beginning and just do `> /file/to/empty`

Comment: You can also do `> /file/to/empty`.

Answer (score 7):

The usual way to rotate the logs with NginX is to rename the file, and then `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`. The server starts a new file, and you can do what you wish with the old.

You may also find it useful to edit the configuration to not log as much....

Answer (score 2):

have a look in the nginx config, check who the server is running as - at a guess the user will be nginx

so :

`chown nginx: /var/run/nginx.pid`
`chown -R nginx: /var/log/nginx`

Should do the trick.

Comment: but why was it working before?

Comment: I suspect because you tried to run it as root, and then tried starting it with its init script.

Comment: well I always start it like that, hmm....

Comment: nginx.conf says: "user www-data"

Answer (score 2):

> To re-size the file to 0 bytes, without having to re-load or re-start nginx, use the truncate command:
>
> `sudo truncate --size 0 /var/log/nginx/access.log`

Followed the guidance of [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/980572/286054) due to my use case requiring the use of `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the error.log file and nginx will create it itself.

Comment: i deleted it, then when I try and start nginx is gives me the same permission denied error on the file /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: Delete the Log and restart Nginx. It will automatically create the Log.

Answer (score 0):

First try deleting the file, if that doesn't work check that the nobody user has the right permissions:
http://derekneely.com/2009/06/nginx-failed-13-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream/