# Can I delete access log files in nginx. Will it cause an issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, log-files

My access log file takeing more than 100 Go can i delete safely the access log file
Could i delete it as root ? 
Can other users access to this file after recreating it ?

Comment: Make it empty: `echo '' > /var/log/nginx/access.log`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can remove `access.log` as root user, or using sudo.

```
sudo rm /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

**However** after deleting it, the file will not be re-created until `nginx` is re-loaded or re-started. To  reload `nginx` do:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

**To re-size the file to 0 bytes**, without having to re-load or re-start nginx, use the `truncate` command:

```
sudo truncate --size 0 /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Comment: Without reloading nginx how to empty it ?

Comment: edited post - does that help?

Comment: Yes thanks but can I empty the file without reloading or restarting the server have you any idea ?

Comment: I do have an idea for you - see post

Comment: It works super answer suspects thanks

Comment: no probs - welcome

Comment: Will truncating work reliably? In many cases, truncating a file that another process has open will cause it to keep writing at the old position, leaving a huge gap of nulls at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the standard log rotation utility in Linux to rotate your logs and delete old logs. See `man logrotate` for more details.

Comment: This what we do, we rotate nightly.

Comment: config file is located at `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`